# A new pattern of IPv6 addresses in mobile network

Tags: ipv6, mobile, lte, 4g

When I checked the IPv6 addresses in a mobile network from the log, I found a strange IPv6 IID configuration pattern. As shown below, the common part of the IID of IPv6 addresses is `:1:0:`.

```
2401:4900:4aa5:7768:1:0:c0ed:9e41
2401:4900:4aa5:1be0:1:0:be3a:6e0d
2401:4900:4aa5:3a27:1:0:bfcb:d35a
2401:4900:4aa5:52de:1:0:c2ae:b059
2401:4900:4aa5:eca5:1:0:c3b3:a22e
2401:4900:4aa5:9a6d:1:0:ba0e:169f
```

What confused me comes from the RFC6459, named "IPv6 in 3rd Generation Partnership Project (3GPP) Evolved Packet System (EPS)“(5.2. IPv6 Address Configuration). It said: IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration (SLAAC), as specified in [RFC4861] and [RFC4862], is the only supported address configuration mechanism. Stateful DHCPv6-based address configuration [RFC3315] is not supported by 3GPP specifications.

So this is my question: Is pattern `:1:0:` a new SLAAC method different from EUI64(`ff:fe`) and privacy extensions(random)?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here. How a network owner addresses its networks is its own business, and there is nothing that prevents it from numbering it any way it wants. ISPs often do strange things like that that do not conform to RFCs.

Comment: Just because it's "not part of the spec" doesn't mean a carrier can't do it anyway.

Comment: @dianwoshishi MAC address are unique property of Ethernet standards 802.*. Also SLAAC from EUI64 is a unique feature of IPv6 over Enternet (see RFC 2464) Mobile interfaces do not have MAC addresses[1], and cannot use EUI64 SLAAC. From what I understand in LTE at least one interface id is assigned by the network during attach and UE (see e.g. [here](https://blog.wirelessmoves.com/2016/04/how-to-get-an-ipv6-prefix-from-the-lte-network.html)) is free to generate any number of additional ones (see e.g., RFC 8981 for a list of options).

Comment: @dianwoshishi [1] note that some implementation in OSes do show mobile interfaces with MAC addresses, but this is internal OS detail, not what the network sees

Comment: also IPv6 address allocation to mobile device is specified in mobile network standards and is thus a question about "protocol theory", not "network outside your control".